Nav2 MPPI Controller Tuning help
I have been working on Tuning “nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController” of nav2 for accurate path tracking and obstacle avoidance for an Akcerman vehicle with minimum turning radius of 4.5 meters.
Intially I want to achieve accurate path tracking performance. I read the limited documentation available at nav2 docs (Model Predictive Path Integral Controller — Nav2 1.0.0 documentation 2) and Found two critics plays an important role in doing this task. i.e. “PathFollowCritic” and “PathAngleCritc”. So I have disabled all the remaining Critics and enabled these both. But Still vehicle not following the path accurately.
Please find the mpc_params I have used and suggest how to improve my tracking accuracy.
MpcFollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.1
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_std: 0.2
      wz_std: 0.4
      vx_max: 1.0
      vx_min: -0.5
      vy_max: 0.5
      wz_max: 1.9
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 6.0
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "Ackermann"
      visualize: true
      enforce_path_inversion: True
      reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
      regenerate_noises: false
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      AckermannConstraints:
        min_turning_r: 3.5
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: true 
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 4.0
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.5
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: true
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 2.0
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
        inflation_radius: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
      # CostCritic:
      #   enabled: true
      #   cost_power: 1
      #   cost_weight: 3.81
      #   critical_cost: 300.0
      #   consider_footprint: true
      #   collision_cost: 1000000.0
      #   near_goal_distance: 1.0
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 10.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
        trajectory_point_step: 3
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        offset_from_furthest: 20
        use_path_orientations: false
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 10.0
        offset_from_furthest: 5
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 10.0
        offset_from_furthest: 4
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
        mode: 0

